# why curator does not use the connection pool to manager the connection

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I'm new in using curator，i found that some framework use the connection pool to manage the connections like jdbc,redis. but i don't find the connection pool in curator.why curator does not provide the connection pool to reduce the resource which each connection consumes.

Comment: What connection pool are you referring to? Also, how would a connection pool be beneficial?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I mean that when we need 100 connection，the curator will create 100 connections，why not use a connection pool contains 10 connection(just for example)，when i need ,i can get from the pool , used up and put back into the pool.In this way ,we can save some resources in  establishing the connection。I am just a newbie, this is just some of my thoughts.

Comment: Curator does not create 100 connections. There is exactly 1 connection per CuratorFramework instance as there only needs to be 1 connection. I really don't know what you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

One CuratorFramework instance wraps a ZooKeeper instance which in turn maintains a connection to a ZooKeeper node.

[ZooKeeper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/atc10/tech/full_papers/Hunt.pdf) provides the following ordering guarantees:

> - **Linearizable writes**: all requests that update the state of ZooKeeper are serializable and respect precedence;
> - **FIFO client order**: all requests from a given client are executed in the order that they were sent by the client.

Assume there is connection pool with two `CuratorFramework` instances A and B. We issue a write request to A to create a znode `/a` and return A to the connection pool. Then we get another `CuratorFramework` instance from the connection pool. This time we get B. We issue a read request to B to read `/a`. It is possible that we can't get `/a` since there is no guarantee that the read request will be placed after the write request. Only with the same connction, we can ensure the order. So the connection pool has this data inconsistency problem.

Another problem is ephemeral znodes. Ephemeral znodes created with one `CuratorFramework` instance is only visible to itself. With a connection pool, we can read ephemeral znodes only when using the same `CuratorFramework` instance which creates them.